# ReactJs UI project to show on other website

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a doubt, I don't know how to do this if anyone has already done it, please help.
suppose I made a react project and I have linked it on **www.abc.com/xyz**
what I have to do is, I have to send my friends a particular website on whatsapp like **www.abc.com/xyz/user1** , **www.abc.com/xyz/user2** , **www.abc.com/xyz/random**
and after xyz every person has its own UUID kind of thing, and it should show the same react UI on every particular website.
How to achieve this? do i have to change it in React code or from backend do i need to do?

Comment: If you ar using a Webserver like Apache, you can add a rewrite proxy rule where ^/xyz/(.*) shows contents from /xyz

Comment: Thank you bro, it worked, my backend team understood.

Comment: Glad it worked :)